# Avoid navigation in react.js on button click

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react.js and trying to create a react component to render a json response from a REST API created in Python-Flask on button click.
Everything works fine but I am being navigated to the same page again and output which is a table does not persist.
We can see the console shows navigation back to the same page, which resets the component's state.

[Snapshot of the console output shows the behavior](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpandya1990/dmft_search_engine/master/Images/Screenshot%20from%202017-03-04%2018-59-23.png)

My component code:

```
    var cols = [
    { key: 'id', label: 'Id' },
    { key: 'owner', label: 'Owner' },    
    { key: 'path', label: 'Path' },
    { key: 'description', label: 'Description' }
];

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: [], searchString: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({searchString: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.items);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.searchString);
    // event.preventDefault();
    // this.getMoviesFromApiAsync();
    console.log(this.state.searchString);
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    // Todo: Append the searchstring to the URI
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/search")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log("Inside request: ");
        console.log(json.Data);
        this.setState({
          items: json.Data
        });
        console.log("after copy to state");
        console.log(this.state.items);
      });
  }

  generateRows() {
        var cols = this.props.cols,  // [{key, label}]
            data = this.state.items;
        console.log("Inside functions");
        console.log(data);
            // console.log(data);

        return data.map(function(item) {
            // handle the column data within each row
            var cells = cols.map(function(colData) {

                // colData.key might be "firstName"
                return <td key={colData.key}> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
            });
            return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
        });
    }

  generateHeaders() {
    var cols = this.props.cols;  // [{key, label}]

    // generate our header (th) cell components
    return cols.map(function(colData) {
        return <th key={colData.key}> {colData.label} </th>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    var headerComponents = this.generateHeaders(),
        rowComponents = this.generateRows();
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead> {headerComponents} </thead>
                <tbody> {rowComponents} </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = SearchForm;
const main = document.getElementById('main');
ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm cols={cols}/>, main);
```

Comment: You should not need this.handleSubmit.bind(this) within the form itself (you already do the binding in the constructor). Does this still occur even if you uncomment event.preventDefault?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe the default event for form submit is the redirection to same page.

Comment: That was my thoughts as well. Did that work out for you?

Comment: Yes. It works out perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting this as an answer for future reference. When using a form, the event handler for form submission needs to have

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in order to keep the default form submission and redirect from happening.

[Reference](http://devdocs.io/dom/event/preventdefault)

Comment: Other options at your disposal include [`event.stopPropogation`](http://devdocs.io/dom/event/stoppropagation) and its cousin [`event.stopImmediatePropogation`](http://devdocs.io/dom/event/stopimmediatepropagation), depending on what level of control you need Re event bubbling.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info Josh H.